# Use of Converting User thread -> Daemon thread

Tags: java, multithreading, daemon

I read, daemon threads are used and controlled by JVM. JVM creates them and also looks after their termination.User threads are controlled by user.
It is also said, we can convert a user thread to daemon thread by calling `setDaemon()` method.

But, ***`what is the use of such conversion`*** ? Does JVM takes the control of user thread once it has become a dameon thread ?

Let me know if I missed something.

Thanks.

Comment: sgokales,is there any significance in converting a user thread to daemon thread(in terms of memory,etc)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe that user and daemon threads are always under the JVM's control.  (If that wasn't the case, who would be in charge?)

Here's the distinction (from http://www.xyzws.com/javafaq/what-is-difference-between-user-and-daemon-thread-in-java/196):

> The difference between these two types
>   of threads is straightforward: If the
>   Java runtime determines that the only
>   threads running in an application are
>   daemon threads (i.e., there are no
>   user threads in existence) the Java
>   runtime promptly closes down the
>   application, effectively stopping all
>   daemon threads dead in their tracks.
>   In order for an application to
>   continue running, it must always have
>   at least one live user thread. In all
>   other respects the Java runtime treats
>   daemon threads and user threads in
>   exactly the same manner.

Answer (score 7):

Daemon threads don't prevent the application from shutting down while they're still doing work. They're more for tasks that need to be done while the app is alive, but are safe to kill off otherwise.